# Can I use java to make scroll down action on instagram followers/following windows?

Tags: java, selenium, bots, instagram

I see everyone is using Python for instagram automation. I want to use java. Is that possible? If so, I think I must switch frame or windows but I can't see anything in DOM structure that relates to windows/frames for instagram following/followers windows.

Any help is appreciated,

best

Comment: If you want to scrap data from Instagram followers/following windows, then scraping is not a good choice.  Instagram provides a pretty nice API, so try that. And also add more information to your question.

Comment: I want to compare my followers and following list to find out who's not following me back. I am not sure if an API can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do scrollBy on the scroller element

Eg:

[image]

here the scroll element is a unique element with class `isgrP`

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
scroll = driver.findElement(By.className("isgrP"))
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrolBy(0,arguments[0].scrollHeight)",scroll);
```

Comment: this works for me. So thank you very much! One last thing though. I impement this with a while loop and I want to break out when the scroll bar hits the most bottom (Of course in the mean time I will be getting follower names in an arraylist). Do you know how can I implement this?

Comment: Just add a while loop with followers count  , break for loop if count remain same

Comment: BurakhanAksoy, if you don't mind can you please share the code of yours. Because I'm facing the same issue and approach from @PDHide didn't seem to be working for me. Not sure what's wrong with my code.